# multiple <ref> in <property> in spring xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am new to spring, i have three bean id such as answerBean1,answerBean2,answerBean3 and should include them in bean questionBean using `<property>`. I am able to assign one bean as ref but when assign multiple bean i am getting error. I dont need to use `<constuctor-arg>` for this work.

```
<bean id="answerBean1" class="com.spring.java.CICollection.Answer">
<property name="id" value="101"></property>
<property name="answerText" value="Collection of constants and method declarations"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="answerBean2" class="com.spring.java.CICollection.Answer">
<property name="id" value="102"></property>
<property name="answerText" value="Collection of abstract method and constants"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="answerBean3" class="com.spring.java.CICollection.Answer">
<property name="id" value="103"></property>
<property name="answerText" value="Constants and abstract methods"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="questionBean" class="com.spring.java.CICollection.Question">
<property name="id" value="101"></property>
<property name="questionText" value="What is interface?"></property>
<property name="answerList" >
<ref bean="answerBean1"/>
 <ref bean="answerBean2"/>
<ref bean="answerBean3"/>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What is the type of answerList?

Comment: embed the refs in `<list>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you were already told in the comments, you should put bean refs inside `<list>` tags, if `answerList` is of type `java.util.List`. Other wrapper elements are `<set>`, `<map>` and `<props>` for `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Map` and `java.util.Properties` respectively. Take a look at [these examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_injecting_collection.htm) for more info.

```
<bean id="questionBean" class="com.spring.java.CICollection.Question">
    <property name="id" value="101"></property>
    <property name="questionText" value="What is interface?"></property>
    <property name="answerList" >
        <list>
            <ref bean="answerBean1"/>
            <ref bean="answerBean2"/>
            <ref bean="answerBean3"/>
        <list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `answerList` is of type list, then you should put multiple `ref` in list tag only. Like this below code-

```
<bean id="questionBean" class="com.spring.java.CICollection.Question">
<property name="id" value="101"></property>
<property name="questionText" value="What is interface?"></property>
<property name="answerList">
    <list>
        <ref bean="answerBean1"/>
        <ref bean="answerBean2"/>
        <ref bean="answerBean3"/>
    </list>
</property>

...

</bean>
```